# how to model colors in graph database [neo4j[

Tags: colors, model, neo4j

I am practicing with Neo4j. I am trying to model colors and their relationships but I don't know what to do with different names of colors.
For example, it looks like (from what I read on the internet), aqua, cyan, teal are more or less the same color.

I want to model colors such as I can classify each color in it's category (primary, secondary, tertiary), in its family (warm, cool, neutral).

I also want to represent shades, tints and tones of different colors.

How do I model that x is a tint of y and y is a primary color for example? It is becoming difficult.
I want each color to be a SEPARATE NODE.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly this really depends on how you want to query your data.  You could represent color as simply as a hex code or a serialized JSON string of the properties that you describe above and then you would just need a property.  But if colors are a fundamental part of your model then you could get really detailed and split things out into individual nodes and relationships.  I'll assume that here.

So you could have, for example, `Color`, `Level`, `Family`, `Shade`, etc... labels.  For the labels after `Color` you could just create all of them upfront, or you could use `MERGE` to create them only when necessary.

Then you could simply create color nodes and relationships like:

```
CREATE (color:Color {hex: '#FFFFFF', name: 'White'})
```

and then:

```
MATCH (white:Color {hex: '#FFFFFF'}), (primary:Level {name: 'Primary'})
CREATE (white)-[:IS_LEVEL]->(primary)
```

Again, this would be if you want to query by finding common paths between colors.  If you just want to be able to tell if `#FFFFFF` is a primary color you could have a `level` property with the vaule `Primary`.

Side note: I suggest reading Randall Munroe's [color survey results](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) blog post because it is awesome.

**EDIT:**

Based in your comment, if you want to have different names for a color you could either have an array property for the `name` (or perhaps a `name` property which is a string and an `alternative_names` property which is an array), or you could have a `ColorName` node with a `name` property and then a `(:Color)-[:HAS_NAME]->(:ColorName)` relationship.

One consideration if your database were to grow very large is that Neo4j doesn't yet support indexing on array properties (I think you could do it with legacy indexes, though).  So something like this would work:

```
MATCH (color:Color) WHERE 'Red' IN color.names RETURN *
```

But it will need to look through ever `Color` node.  If you had a `ColorName` label then you could make an index for `ColorName(name)`.  But it does come with the tradeoff that the more you extract properties into separate nodes, your queries start becoming more difficult to maintain because you need to include those extra nodes every time you want to display information about a color.  You start to get into queries like;

```
MATCH (color:Color)
WHERE color.hex = '#FFFFFF'
OPTIONAL MATCH (color)-[:HAS_LEVEL]->(level:ColorLevel)
WITH color, level
OPTIONAL MATCH (color)-[:HAS_NAME]->(color_name:ColorName)
WITH color, level, collect(color_name.name) AS names
// etc....
RETURN color, level, names, etc...
```

Comment: Great response. That's the path I took with my modelling. However, I am finding it difficult to handle the "name" property of each color node since multiple colors have different names. How do I handle naming variations such that I can find a node whether it's referred to as cyan or aqua.